# try function in parsing lambda expressions

Tags: parsing, haskell, lambda

I'm totally new to Haskell and trying to implement a "Lambda calculus" parser, that will be used to read the input to a lambda reducer .. It's required to parse bindings first "identifier = expression;" from a text file, then at the end there's an expression alone ..
till now it can parse bindings only, and displays errors when encountering an expression alone .. when I try to use the `try` or `option` functions, it gives a type mismatch error:

> ```
> Couldn't match type `[Expr]'
>                   with `Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 [[Expr]]'
>     Expected type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
>                      s0 u0 m0 (Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 [[Expr]])
>       Actual type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 [Expr]
>     In the second argument of `option', namely `bindings'
> ```

bindings weren't supposed to return anything, but I tried to add a return statement and it also returned a type mismatch error:

> ```
> Couldn't match type `[Expr]' with `Expr'
>     Expected type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
>                      [Char] u0 Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Expr]
>       Actual type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
>                      [Char] u0 Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [[Expr]]
>     In the second argument of `(<|>)', namely `expressions'
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't use `<|>` if you want to allow both

Your `program` parser does its main work with

```
program = do
      spaces
      try bindings <|> expressions
      spaces >> eof
```

This `<|>` is choice - it does `bindings` if it can, and if that fails, `expressions`, which isn't what you want. You want zero or more bindings, followed by expressions, so let's make it do that. 
Sadly, even when this works, the last line of your parser is `eof` and

First, let's allow zero bindings, since they're optional, then let's get both the bindings and the expressions:

```
bindings = many binding

program = do
      spaces
      bs <- bindings 
      es <- expressions
      spaces >> eof
      return (bs,es)
```

This error would be easier to find with plenty more `<?> "binding"` type hints so you can see more clearly what was expected.

### `endBy` doesn't need `many`

The error message you have stems from the line

```
expressions = many (endBy expression eol)
```

which should be

```
expressions :: Parser [Expr]
expressions = endBy expression eol
```

`endBy` works like `sepBy` - you don't need to use `many` on it because it already parses many.

This error would have been easier to find with a stronger data type tree, so:

### Use `try` to deal with common prefixes

One of the hard-to-debug problems you've had is when you get the error `expecting space or "="` whilst parsing an expression. If we think about that, the only place we expect `=` is in a binding, so it must be part way through parsing a binding when we've given it an expression. This only happens if our expression starts with an identifier, just like a binding does.

`binding` sees the first identifier and says "It's OK guys, I've got this" but then finds no `=` and gives you an error, where we wanted it to backtrack and let `expression` have a go. The key point is we've already used the identifier input, and we want to unuse it. `try` is right for that.

Encase your `binding` parser with `try` so if it fails, we'll go back to the start of the line and hand over to `expression`.

```
binding = try (do
          (Var id) <- identifier
          _ <- char '='
          spaces
          exp <- expression
          spaces
          eol <?> "end of line"
          return $ Eq id exp
        <?> "binding")
```

It's important that as far as possible each parser starts with matching something unique to avoid this problem. (`try` is backtracking, hence inefficient, so should be avoided if possible.)

In particular, avoid starting parsers with `spaces`, but instead make sure you finish them all with spaces. Your main `program` can start with `spaces` if you like, since it's the only alternative.

### Use types for most productions - better structure & readability

My first piece of general advice is that you could do with a more fine-grained data type, and should annotate your parsers with their type. At the moment, everything's wrapped up in `Expr`, which means you can only get error messages about whether you have an `Expr` or a `[Expr]`. The fact that you had to add `Eq` to `Expr` is a sign you're pushing the type too far.

Usually it's worth making a data type for quite a lot of the productions, and if you `import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>),(<$>),many)` [Control.Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a-60--42--62-) you can use `<$>` and `<*>` so that the production, the datatype and the parser are all the same structure:

```
--<program> ::= <spaces> [<bindings>] <expressions>
data Program = Prog [Binding] [Expr]
program = spaces >> Prog <$> bindings <*> expressions   

-- <expression> ::=  <abstraction> | factors
data Expression = Ab Abstraction | Fa [Factor] 
expression = Ab <$> abstraction <|> Fa <$> factors   <?> "expression"
```

Don't do this with letters for example, but for important things. What counts as important things is a matter of judgement, but I'd start with Identifiers. (You can use `<*` or `*>` to not include syntax like `=` in the results.)

### Amended code:

Before refactoring types and using Applicative [here](http://lpaste.net/99885)

And afterwards [here](http://lpaste.net/99918)

Comment: Thank you .. I tried to make the modifications you mentioned, but when the parser reaches the line that has an expression only it displays an error & expects a binding: `code` unexpected "("
expecting space or "="

Comment: I defined Binding as:
data Binding = Eq Symbol Expr  
the type of bindings & binding is:
bindings :: Parser [Binding]
binding :: Parser Binding

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm parsing bracketed expressions OK with a corrected but not improved version like [this](http://lpaste.net/99885). If that doesn't work, can you post your `"Program.txt"`?

Comment: It still returns the same error when parsing an expression, "Program.txt" contains an expression only after removing all the bindings:
`eq (div (add 2 7) (sub 5 2)) 3;`

Comment: @user3305447 Ah yes - `expression` and `binding` can both start with an identifier, so `binding` has a go and fails expecting `=`. It's the common prefix problem. See new version of answer.

Comment: @user3305447 see also new links at bottom to edited code

Comment: Thank you so much .. Could you please explain how to build a reducer that reduces this lambda expression after parsing this [text file](http://lpaste.net/3890772459258904576) using the above parser .. We're supposed to replace each identifier with its equivalent expression, then reduce the whole expression to the normal form using lambda reduction rules.

Comment: That's a new question, so give it a go and then post what you've got explaining where you're stuck. You're doing well. Ideas: First you'll need to add `IfThenElse` to `Expression` and a parser for it. Next you need to have an `eval` function. There are plenty of tutorials online that have a Lambda calculus evaluator, so have a look how other folk are doing it.

Comment: I'm already trying to understand [this code](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/reducer.hs), but the reduction part seems a little bit complex.
How can I retrieve the elements of a second list from a list of list?, in the result `Prog [Binding] [Expr]` I need to separate [Expr] in a different list to be able to loop on each identifier and replacing it with its equivalent expression from the bindings list.

Comment: I got the lists, Could you please explain how to iterate on the expression string and replacing each identifier with its equivalent expression from the bindings list? @enough rep to comment

Comment: @user3305447 You should use Data.Map for soring the bindings, I think. Look it up on hoogle or stackoverflow. Don't iterate on the expression string, write a function from the Expression type to values & functions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer .. I think it could be implemented using 'map' function, like this `newE = map [\x -> getExp(b) | x <- eStr, b <- bs, x == getId(b)]
                where es = getExpressions (prog)
                      bs = getBindings (prog)
                      -- Extracting expression into an array of strings
                      eStr = map (delete '(') (map (delete '(') (map (delete ')') words es))
` but I'm getting errors of course. Could you please give me the correct answer. & bindings are supposed to be sorted in the text file already.

Comment: Any help with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818121/join-function-and-type-issues-haskell)?