# join function and type issues haskell

Tags: haskell, join, types

I have 2 lists Expressions and bindings (id = Expr), and trying to replace each expression with its equivalent from the bindings list in a new list called newE, where Expression = id ..
Initially, I have only one expression:

> eq (div (add 2 7) (sub 5 2)) 3

I want to replace each identifier in this expression with its equivalent from the bindings list, so I tried to split this expression into a list of strings and removed brackets, to separate each identifier  ..

This is how I tried to implement it:

```
newE = [\x -> getExp(b) | x <- eStr, b <- bs, x == getId(b)]
                where es = getExpressions (prog)
                      bs = getBindings (prog)
                      -- Extracting expression into a list of strings 
                      -- and removing brackets
                      eStr = map (delete ')')(map (delete ')') 
                             (map (delete '(') (split " " (show es))))
newE' = join " " newE
```

Is this correct?

Now I'm getting errors that newE returns [t0 -> Expr] while it's supposed to return Expr only, why is that?

and the join function is expecting a [Char] .. while its type in the [Data.List.Utils](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-0.18.6/docs/Data-List-Utils.html) documentation is:

join :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]

so, isn't it supposed to accept any type not just list of characters? or did it get confused with a 'join' from another library?
I searched the libraries I've imported, but they don't have a join.

Any help to resolve these errors and modify the code to do what it's supposed to do?

Thank you

Comment: Just to make sure I understand everything, does your example expression `eq (div (add 2 7) (sub 5 2)) 3` have any identifiers in it? Are `eq`, `div`, `add`, `sub` your identifiers?

Comment: Your other problem is that you're trying to use a string to represent an expression. You'll have an easier time if you use an algebraic data type - something like [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT#Arithmetic_expressions)

Comment: yes, they are the identifiers. `2`,`7`,`5`,`3` are identifiers also and they have equivalent lambda expressions in the bindings list .. [here's the file](http://lpaste.net/3890772459258904576) they're read from.

Comment: [These](http://lpaste.net/8825926431981699072) are the data types I'm using.

Comment: I just converted the Expression into a list of strings to be able to use the Data.List functions on it.

Comment: Work with the expression as an `Expr` value - it will be a lot easier.

Comment: How? Is there another way other than list comprehensions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked, here is a sketch of the conventional approach:

1. Convert the string expression into a `Expr` value, e.g.

   add 2 7 -> App (App (Var "add") (Var "2")) (Var "7")
2. Write a function `lookupBinding` to lookup a binding for a Symbol:

   lookupBinding :: [Binding] -> Symbol -> Maybe Expr
3. Write a substitute function to substitute binding definitions into an expression:

   substitute :: [Binding] -> Expr -> Expr

It will go something like this:

```
substitute bindings (App e1 e2) = App e1' e2'
  where e1' = substitute bindings e1
        e2' = substitute bindings e2

substitute bindings (Var sym) = ... lookupBinding sym ...
substitute bindings (Lam sym exp) = ... substitute bindings' exp ...
```

Comment: Thank you .. I tried to implement lookupBinding that way:
`lookupBinding bs id = if null e' then Var id else head e'
                           where e' = [ e | Eq s e <- bs, id == s]
` But it only works one time and in the second time, I get the error: `Non-exhaustive patterns in function substitute`

Comment: You should start a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension body returns the function `\x -> getExp b`. That's why the compiler says it's returning a function type.

Comment: What's the correct form to return only expressions?